# React Native 0.57.3. Unable to resolve module

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a clean build of react-native. Each time I run react-native run-ios I seem to get build errors stating that modules can't be found. Can't see any issues with my code.

Been having this issue for the last couple of days and going round in circles.

react-native: 0.57.3
XCode: 9.4.1

Any ideas?

Simulator screen warning here
[image: Simulator screen shot]

'FirstScreen' Code referencing the common module here
[image: FirstScreen code]

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
    "react-native": "0.57.3",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.0-alpha.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-external-helpers": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.48.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: `FirstScreen` is not imported properly. Post code where you are importing your FirstScreen

Comment: Please, do not post your code as an image otherwise it cannot be copied to reproduce the error to provide and test an answer.

Comment: apologies vivek/isma - I posted it as a screenshot to show the code next to the folder structure in atom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your folder structure, the following line is wrong:

```
import { Input, Button } from "../common";
```

Since compiler will look for either a file named common.js, or common/index.js. None of those exists.

Instead, you have to do:

```
import Input from "../common/Input";
import Button from "../common/Button";
```

Or, if you still want to keep that line of code, add a file named `index.js` to folder `common`, and add following code:

```
export { default as Input } from "./Input"
export { default as Button } from "./Button"
```

Comment: argh thanks! Wood for the trees. I started off with a haste cache problem and so started writing my code again file by file to try to get to the bottom of it - missed the obvious - thanks!